# Insert complex value to an existing array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, razor

I need to create a list of struct type (complex model) on JavaScript using ASDP.NET MVC3

```
var myItems = new Array(@Model.Count());    
var CreatedItem;
for (i = 1 ; i<= @Model.Count()-1;i++)
{
    CreatedItem = {
        'DayPartID': i,
        'Name': $("#Name_"+i).val(),
        'IsEnable': $("#IsEnable_"+i).val(),
        'Time': $('#timepicker-'+ i).val()
    };

    myItems.push(CreatedItem);
    alert(myItems[i]);
}
```

Problem is that I can not obtain "myItems" filled correctly after repetitive structure "for" ends.

Comment: Does that work? http://pastebin.com/TieyfEjF I converted the code of @Neel's answer by mistake, but just remove the `localStorage` things.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your array like:

```
var arr = new Array(2);
```

Then you do:

```
arr.push("foo");
```

This will give you:

```
[ undefined, undefined, "foo" ]
```

---

Either change the initialaztion to an empty array like:

```
var myItems = [];
```

Or don't push, but set, like:

```
myItems[i] = CreatedItem;
```

---

Also, your loop starts at `1` - that's weird. Change to:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < @Model.Count(); i += 1) {
```

Comment: Is not simple list like your example " arr.push("foo"); " , it is complex like : arr.push("item1","item2","item7");

Comment: That doesn't change anything. `arr.push("item1","item2","item7");` is the same as `arr.push("item1"); arr.push("item2"); arr.push("item7");`